# jQuery $.ajax data gets lost if URL is modified in beforeSend. Why?

Tags: jquery

I have an ajax call with jQuery, which will have a different URL based on a `input select`.

This is my code:

```
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {csrf: wpApiSettings.nonce},
                beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
                    if (addressType === 'sender') {
                        this.url = '/api/private/autocomplete/sender-countries/';
                    } else if (addressType === 'destination') {
                        this.url = '/api/private/autocomplete/destination-countries/';
                    } else {
                        xhr.abort();
                    }
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.success) callback(response.data);
                }
            });
```

I tried many things, but the request data gets always deleted if one of the conditions in beforeSend is true and the URL gets modified. I found this out by declaring an URL like you will normally do in the ajax function. If the beforeSend conditions are never met, the data with the nonce is sent. If the url is modified in beforeSend, no data with nonce is sent to the server.

Can someone help me out please with this? Redeclaring the data inside beforeSend sounds weird, why isn't this working in the first place?

Comment: Why are you doing this in `beforeSend` instead of just doing it in the function that calls `$.ajax`?

Comment: What if you assign to `settings.url` instead of `this.url`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify `method: 'POST'`, so this sends a GET request by default. The parameters of a GET request are appended to the URL.

This is done before the `beforeSend` function is called, so if it modifies the URL this concatenation is lost.

So if you're going to customize the URL in `beforeSend`, you'll need to append the parameters yourself.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {csrf: wpApiSettings.nonce},
    beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
        if (addressType === 'sender') {
            settings.url = '/api/private/autocomplete/sender-countries/?' + $.param(settings.data);
        } else if (addressType === 'destination') {
            settings.url = '/api/private/autocomplete/destination-countries/?' + $.param(settings.data);
        } else {
            xhr.abort();
        }
    },
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.success) callback(response.data);
    }
});
```

But a simpler solution is to move the condition outside the call.

```
if (address_type === 'sender' || address_type = 'destination') {
    $.ajax({
        url: `/api/private/autocomplete/${address_type}-countries/`,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {csrf: wpApiSettings.nonce},
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.success) callback(response.data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i didn't realised the facts about the default GET request. I used the simpler solution with the condition outside, che code looks cleaner this way.